# How do I override template-tags.php in 2021 theme

Tags: theme-twenty-twenty-one

I've created a child theme and I want to overwrite functions in inc/template-tags.php file. I thought if I copy this file and recreate folder structure in my child them then it will work but it doesn't? How to do it properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice how the [parent theme](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/6babc3833b0a06cc09ca7643df09a5443b14059f/wp-content/themes/twentytwentyone/inc/template-tags.php#L57) checks if they are already defined e.g.

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'twenty_twenty_one_entry_meta_footer' ) ) {
   ...
}
```

Then just define them in your child theme's `functions.php` file, to override the corresponding template tag.

It should work because the child theme's `functions.php` file is loaded before the parent's `functions.php` file that [loads](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/6babc3833b0a06cc09ca7643df09a5443b14059f/wp-content/themes/twentytwentyone/functions.php#L539):

```
// Custom template tags for the theme.
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/template-tags.php';
```

Comment: Thanks, yes I already figured it out.